# Check User Credentials at Launch (Sign In With Apple) with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I just implemented Sign In With Apple in my SwiftUI App using the examples I found on the web.
Works great but I have a very important question: Where should I do the Check if the user is validated or not?

I have a function checkUserAuth() that returns 3 states: undefined, signedOut and signedIn. Based on each one of those returns, I want to open a different View.

```
self.signInWithAppleManager.checkUserAuth { (authenticationState) in
    switch authenticationState {
    case .undefined:
        print("AuthenticationState: .undefined")
    case .signedOut:
        print("AuthenticationState: .signedOut")
    case .signedIn:
        print("AuthenticationState: .signedIn")
    }
}
```

If my function returns .undefined or .signedOut, I want to open the LoginView.swift. If the function returns .signIn, I want to open the MainView.swift.

Where should I make this Check?
Should I do that on the SceneDelegate.swift and show the right View or should a have a View responsible to make this validation and "navigate" to the right view?

Thanks I hope I could explain my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My fast solution suggests to persist this state in some `@Published var` and check it in the needed view. It does not looks good, maybe better create checking functions somewhere else (like viewModel), but I think it will direct you to the right way:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class SingSingInWithAppleManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var userAuthState: UserAuthInAppleState

    init() { // here you can check auth status
        userAuthState = .undefined
    }

    func logIn() {
        // here you're making login in and change status
        userAuthState = .signedIn
    }

}

enum UserAuthInAppleState {
    case undefined
    case signedOut
    case signedIn
}

struct SingInWithAppleExample: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var signInWithAppleManager: SingSingInWithAppleManager

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            if signInWithAppleManager.userAuthState == .undefined {
                Button(action:
                    {
                        self.signInWithAppleManager.logIn()
                }) {
                    Text("Login in!")
                }
            } else {
                Text("singed in!")
            }

        }

    }
}

// MARK: how to make it with animation
struct SingInWithAppleExample: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var signInWithAppleManager: SingSingInWithAppleManager

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Button(action:
                {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.signInWithAppleManager.logIn()
                    }
            }) {
                Text("Login in!")
            }
            .opacity(signInWithAppleManager.userAuthState == .undefined ? 1 : 0)

            Text("singed in!")
                .opacity(signInWithAppleManager.userAuthState == .signedIn ? 1 : 0)

        }

    }
}
```

I think you should set this manager in the `SceneDelegate` func if it's the first thing you want to show. Here is `PreviewProvider` example:

```swift
struct SingInWithAppleExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SingInWithAppleExample()
            .environmentObject(SingSingInWithAppleManager()) // only add this line of code
    }
}
```

**P.S** can you share "examples you found on the web" please, soon I'll need to implement it too